# Javascript SOAP Request, Return String

Tags: javascript, wcf, soap

What I'm attempting seems relatively simple, but I can't seem to find a simple answer on how to do it. I have a WCF Web Service that is self hosted. It has one function that accepts zero parameters and returns a string. All I want to do is request that method from javascript and capture that string response in javascript

Here is the code I have, and so far it won't even return anything. I can get requests easily if I use something like SOAPUI.

**App.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="test.XKORE.MobileDeviceServices.Properties.Settings.ConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=tester;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=testc;Password=testp" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="test.XKORE.MobileDeviceServices.XKOREMobileService" behaviorConfiguration="XKOREMobileServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8523/test/XKORE/XKOREMobileService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="test.XKORE.MobileDeviceServices.IXKOREMobileService" bindingNamespace="http://test.XKORE.MobileDeviceServices" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="test.XKORE.MobileDeviceServices.IXKOREMobileService" bindingNamespace="http://test.XKORE.MobileDeviceServices" />

      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="XKOREMobileServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

**Interface**

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IXKOREMobileService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetChartData();

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }
```

**SOAP Request**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IXKOREMobileService/GetChartData</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetChartData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**Javascript (Not Working)**

```
var response = BuildSOAPMessage('GetChartData');
alert(response);

function BuildSOAPMessage (func) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8523/test/XKORE/XKOREMobileService", true);

    var msg = '';
    msg += '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
    msg += '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">'
    msg += '<soapenv:Header/>'
    msg += '<soapenv:Body>'
    msg += '<tem:' + func + '/>'
    msg += '</soapenv:Body>'
    msg += '</soapenv:Envelope>'
    alert (msg);

     // Send the POST request
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IXKOREMobileService/GetJSONChartData");
     xmlhttp.send(msg);

    return xmlhttp.responseXML;
}
```

Comment: I see no javascript code here. Are you confusing java and javascript?

Comment: @Cfreak That's kind of what I was looking for. That's the part I'm stuck at. I'll edit the post to include what I have so far in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this thread and opening a separate one since the issue is more related to cross domain problems.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in your code:

- You specified that the XmlHttpRequest object will be asynchronous (passing `true` in the third parameter to the `open` call). That means you don't get the results after calling `send`, you need to wait for the event to access the responseXML property.
- It's very likely that you're hitting a cross-domain restriction. XMLHttpRequest cannot, by default, send requests to sites other than the one where the page arrived. You're self-hosting the WCF service, and I'm assuming that the page which hosts the JavaScript code is coming from some other domain. That will be blocked by the browser.

Comment: Alright that makes sense. What's the best way to get around the cross-domain restriction?

Comment: The domain isn't just based on the machine - different ports, HTTP vs. HTTPS, they all mean different domains. `http://mysite.com:8000` is a different domain than `http://mysite.com`, and different than `https://mysite.com`

Comment: Yeah I realized that after I posted it, so then I edited my post. Is there an easy way to get around the restriction?